# Puppet: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Unknown resource type: 'ini_setting'

Tags: linux, puppet

I am trying to edit my puppet agents check-in time but cannot get it to run the command `ini_settting` I have been following this guide as an example: [link](https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/networking_and_servers/9781784394882/4/ch04lvl1sec60/editing-ini-style-files-with-puppetlabs-inifile)

```
  ini_setting {'server_true':
    path    => '/tmp/server.conf',
    section => 'main',
    setting => 'server',
    value   => 'true',
  }
```

However, when I run anything with `ini_setting`, I get: Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Unknown resource type: 'ini_setting' at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/test.pp

I have also tried declaring it in a class, with the same error. I have also tried `inifile::setting { 'agent_runinterval':` from this guide [link](https://ask.puppet.com/question/10953/how-to-change-check-in-interval-from-puppet-master/) with the same problem.

My check-in code looks as follows:

test.pp

```
ini_setting { "agent_runinterval":
        ensure => present,
        path => "/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf",
        section => "main",
        settting => "runinterval",
        value => "21600"
}
```

I checked the config file is targeted correctly:

```
 cat /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/puppet.conf
 # This file can be used to override the default puppet settings.
```

As per the puppet [docs](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/configuration.html) I should be able to add runinterval to main

**NOTE:** I am NOT looking to make a manual change to the config file here.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't mention it explicitly, have you installed the [inifile module](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/inifile)?

Comment: @larsks Thanks! I thought I had it in my base puppet installer template, but turns out it failed along the way. All good now, thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Larsks idea above, turns out the module failed along the way.

Manual install of using `puppet module install puppetlabs-inifile --version 2.0.0`, and all good. Thanks again.